# Did not find reference matching RestoreAssemblyResources AssemblyName metadata

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

For some time now I have come across some errors in the references in Xamarin. This has taken my sleep and locked my development process. Investigating the structure of the application the reference appears with an alert signal. In the Nuget package manager it appears as installed, but in the process of compiling or deploying the project the exception occurs. The message says it could not find the reference. In an attempt to solve the error, I have already cleaned, compiled, and recompiled the solution. I also edited the .csproj file but no solution was efficient.
I would like to open this discussion to investigate the causes and an efficient and definitive way to solve this error. I count on everyone's help.

**Error**

Did not find reference matching RestoreAssemblyResources AssemblyName metadata 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations'

**Image 01**

[image: Print 01]

**Image 02**

[image: Print 02]

Comment: Cannot remember if I hit that exact error but [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/284460/#Comment_284460) post mentions a corrupt assembly being cached. So you might try: uninstalling the NuGet, delete all **/obj/** and **/bin/** folders, go into **/packages/** and delete the folder for that NuGet, now delete NuGet's local user cache directory by going to the following directory and deleting everything within it (you could just delete all versions of the specific NuGet as well): **%LOCALAPPDATA%\NuGet\Cache**

Comment: Also it sounds like maybe you already tried commenting out references to the library in your **.csproj** file, like they talk about [here](http://evanp.net/xamarin-did-not-find-reference-matching-restoreassemblyresources-assemblyname-metadata/)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, It works for me:

1. right click "Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations" in your Android project `Reference`, remove it.
2. delete package tag with id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations" in Android project's `packages.config` file
   [image]

3.Manage your Android NuGet package and uninstall Annotations package and reinstall it.

4.If still not working, then try clean project, build project and delete all the `obj` and `bin` file in each folder, restart VS.

Comment: Hey. I can't find packages.config